# Flask-SocketIO: How to resume audio streaming from the last known timestamp after a page refresh?

Tags: flask, web, socket.io, flask-socketio

I am developing a Flask web application that streams audio using Flask-SocketIO. I have implemented functionality to store the current playing song and its timestamp using global variables. The server sends updates to the client using SocketIO.

However, I am facing challenges in adjusting the Flask-SocketIO and audio streaming logic to resume playback from the saved timestamp after a page refresh. Currently, the audio always starts from the beginning when the page is refreshed.

```
from flask import Flask, Response, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.utils import mediainfo
from io import BytesIO
import os
import threading
import mysql.connector
import schedule
import time

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

# Directory where songs are stored
SONGS_DIRECTORY = "songs"

# MySQL database configuration
DB_CONFIG = {
    "host": "localhost",
    "user": "admin",
    "password": "admin@123",
    "database": "radio"
}

# Global variables to store current playing song and timestamp
current_song = None
current_timestamp = 0

# Connect to the MySQL database
def db_connect():
    return mysql.connector.connect(**DB_CONFIG, autocommit=True)

# Load songs into the database
def load_songs():
    song_paths = [os.path.join(SONGS_DIRECTORY, file) 
                  for file in os.listdir(SONGS_DIRECTORY) 
                  if file.endswith(".mp3")]

    conn = db_connect()
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    # Clear existing data from the songs table
    cursor.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE songs")

    # Insert songs into the database
    for song_path in song_paths:
        song_name = os.path.basename(song_path)
        audio_info = mediainfo(song_path)
        duration_seconds = round(float(audio_info["duration"]))

        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO songs (name, path, duration) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",
                       (song_name, song_path, duration_seconds))

    cursor.close()
    conn.close()

# Retrieve the playlist from the database
def get_playlist():
    conn = db_connect()
    cursor = conn.cursor(dictionary=True)
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM songs")
    playlist = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
    return playlist

# Generate an audio stream of all songs
@app.route('/api/stream')
def stream_all():
    def generate():
        global current_song, current_timestamp
        playlist = get_playlist()
        
        for song in playlist:
            if current_song and current_song['id'] == song['id']:
                # If the current song matches, start streaming from the saved timestamp
                song_audio = AudioSegment.from_mp3(song['path'])
                song_audio = song_audio[current_timestamp:]
            else:
                song_audio = AudioSegment.from_mp3(song['path'])
                
            buffer = BytesIO()
            song_audio.export(buffer, format="mp3")
            data = buffer.getvalue()
            yield data

    return Response(generate(), mimetype="audio/mp3")

# Schedule a task to update the playlist every 24 hours
def update_playlist_job():
    load_songs()
    playlist = get_playlist()
    socketio.emit('update_playlist', {'playlist': playlist})

# Schedule the task to run every 24 hours
schedule.every(24).hours.do(update_playlist_job)

# Background thread to run the scheduler
def background_thread():
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)

# SocketIO event for initial playlist retrieval
@socketio.on('get_initial_playlist')
def get_initial_playlist():
    playlist = get_playlist()
    socketio.emit('update_playlist', {'playlist': playlist})

# SocketIO event for connecting clients
@socketio.on('connect')
def handle_connect():
    global current_song, current_timestamp
    socketio.emit('update_playlist', {'playlist': get_playlist()})
    socketio.emit('update_current_song', {'current_song': current_song, 'timestamp': current_timestamp})

    thread = threading.Thread(target=background_thread)
    thread.start()

# SocketIO event to set the current playing song and its timestamp
@socketio.on('set_current_song')
def set_current_song(data):
    global current_song, current_timestamp
    current_song = data['current_song']
    current_timestamp = data['timestamp']
    socketio.emit('update_current_song', data, broadcast=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Load songs into the database
    load_songs()

    # Run Flask-SocketIO app
    socketio.run(app, debug=True, port=8002)
```

I expected that by using the global variables and SocketIO updates, I could resume audio playback from the last known timestamp after a page refresh. However, the current implementation does not achieve this, and the audio always starts from the beginning.

Can someone guide me on how to adjust the Flask-SocketIO and audio streaming logic to achieve the desired behavior? Any help or example code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: it seems it is the client who sets the current song and the timestamp. Are you sure the client is passing the correct timestamp? Maybe it always requests the beginning of the song?